# PHP Arrays, displaying fruits like 1.apple 2.banana, etc

Tags: php, arrays

I have some array:

```
array
  0 => string 'Apple' 
  1 => string 'banana'
  2 => string 'Nanas' 
  3 => string 'Grape'
```

What is the best way to display

```
1. Apple
2. banana
3. Nanas
4. Grape
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: what i can do is 0. Apple 2.Banana etc :|.

Comment: what is the output format? HTML? Plain text?

Comment: html :) or plain but im useing html right now. whats major diffrence anyway ?

Comment: HTML you can use fun things like <li>, whereas plaintext you'd have to write the numbers yourself, based on the position in the array.

Comment: yes but im useing li as the header to, so it will like displaying this 1. 3 Fruits, 2.Apple 3.Banana , 4.etc

Comment: You can do nested lists. Wanna edit your answer with what you're trying to do in full?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the output you are after is HTML, then an [ordered list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html) makes sense:

```
<ol>
<?php foreach($fruits as $fruit) { ?>
    <li><?php echo $fruit; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
foreach($fruits as $index => $fruit) {
    echo ($index+1).". ".$fruit."\n";
}
```

Comment: like this one, but maybe html is better :) thanks for the answer bro.

Answer (score 1):

If HTML

```
<ol>
<?php
foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
    echo "<li>", $fruit;
    }
?>
</ol>
```

Comment: W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2
"LI ... Start tag: required, End tag: optional"

Comment: A personal preference. When using non-strict HTML, I use capital letters for elements (as lowercase tags have their origination with XHTML). But then again, I don't use non-strict HTML.